# Prevent direct url access to files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, security, file-access

Background info:

I am working on a website which will provide image and video content via a subscription service. That is, users should ONLY have access to the image and video content so long as they are logged in successfully. (Note: the log in system uses a combination of MySQL DB - to store the username and password - and php to create new user sessions / authentication etc.)

The problem:

How do I stop a user (logged in or not) from directly accessing the image and video files? For example, a user who is not logged in could access the file directly as follows: www.domain.com/testvideo.mp4 - this would render the video content in the browser for them to watch or share with others. (NOTE: I still need to be able to use / display the image and video files on-site via HTML, CSS, PHP etc)

I have tried several .htaccess solutions (including: RewriteCond/RewriteRule & .htpassword) which have successfully prevented direct access BUT have prevented the ability to use the files on-site via HTML, CSS, PHP etc.

I was thinking that this must be a very common problem and if so, what the best way to resolve it was?

Comment: check if a session is created..if not, dont give access..simplest thing to do..

Comment: Why not try to implement a session id upon login? The system could check for this id and if not present, the url returns a 403.

Comment: You're probably looking for hot-linking  http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/smarter-way-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess/

Comment: These are both fine solutions for a PHP page. The problem I have is that if they access the video file directly (as shown in the post) it bypasses any PHP scripts and loads the file. For example, I obviously can't access session data from an mp4 file.

Comment: @PedroLobito I have tried this method. It successfully prevents direct access but it also doesn't allow the images / videos on my site whch I need to have.

Comment: @jeroen has the best solution I reckon.

Answer (score 3):

It is a pretty common problem with a pretty common solution. In order to force access control you have to invoke a PHP script before serving the file and verify the credentials. Then, if the credentials are valid, serve the actual file.

You may be tempted to serve the file directly from PHP script using something like `readfile`. This is going to kill your server performance and break download resuming for the client.

Luckily there is a solution, when you can hand over the actual file serving back to the web-server.

This works as following:

1. The web-server receives the request to `/file.mp4`.
2. According to the rewrite rules you've set up it directs it to your PHP script `/serve.php` instead.
3. Your script verifies the credentials, e.g. something from the session or cookies.
4. If the credentials are valid, the script issues specially crafted header. It tells the web-server to actually serve the static file. If not, you may as well output a 403 HTTP code.

The example script can be something like:

```
$file = '/tmp/file.mp4'; // it is in your best interest to make this file  inaccessible for a direct download
header('X-Sendfile: ' . $file);
header('Content-Type: ' . contentType($file));
header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
```

In order for this to work you'll have to have mod_xsendfile (https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) installed on your Apache, which is probably already the case for your hoster. You'll also have to drop in some lines to configure it and setup a proper rewrite.

You can fine a lot of stuff on Google by issuing "mod_xsendfile php", which might also help a great deal.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: How would I differentiate between the user accessing the video through the website (such as a javascript video player) and the video via direct url? I guess what I mean, is that a user with correct credentials should be able to access the video (as in watch it) through the JS video player, but not directly, via URL.

Comment: I don't think that's possible conceptually. Downloading the file is exactly what JS video player needs to do to show the content. You may try several tricks to differentiate the requests made by a browser to make a direct download from the ones that your JS player does, but in the end it won't really stop one who really wants to download it from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid that as long as your files are publicly available.

The most common way is to not serve the files directly, but to serve them through php so that you can check the users access before you serve the file. And the files can then reside anywhere on the server where the web-server user (www, apache, etc.) has access but the visitor hasn't.

Check the examples in the php manual on [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) and [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to see how you can serve a file through php. You will find lots of examples here on SO as well.

Comment: Yeah, I see this posted on a few other SO posts, unfortunately, this is for a client whose hosting provider only allows access to the root web folder. As such, the files need to be hosted at this level.

Comment: @dw1991 If it is a linux server, add a `.htaccess` file to the images / videos folder that contains just `deny from all`. That will disallow any access through the web-server but php will be able to read the files just fine. And if your client really wants to serve videos and images through a subscription service they might want to get a decent hosting package ;-)

Comment: Note: Javascript widgets also require access to the files in the form of a URL

Comment: @dw1991 They would get the same php file that serves the content instead, no difference.

Comment: I have tried this solution. However, it would not allow the display of the images / videos on the site. I have even tried adding an exception for the domain and ip address of the site. Any ideas why this would be preventing the display of the files on-site. As I understand, this is not expected behaviour.

Comment: @dw1991 Without seeing the code, that is impossible to say. You should ask a new question with the details of the problem and the code.